# R: casting multiple columns according

Tags: r, casting, reshape

I have this dataset (run it in the command line, to have a look at it)

```
structure(list(Staz = c("Carmagnola", "Chieri", "Chivasso", "Ivrea", 
"Moncalieri", "Orbassano"), Year = c(2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004), Season = c("Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", 
"Autumn", "Autumn"), Avg_T = c(11.7361111111111, 11.7361111111111, 
11.7361111111111, 11.7361111111111, 11.7361111111111, 11.7361111111111
), Min_T = c(7.27222222222222, 7.27222222222222, 7.27222222222222, 
7.27222222222222, 7.27222222222222, 7.27222222222222), Max_T = c(16.6722222222222, 
16.6722222222222, 16.6722222222222, 16.6722222222222, 16.6722222222222, 
16.6722222222222), Moisture = c(69.6388888888889, 69.6388888888889, 
69.6388888888889, 69.6388888888889, 69.6388888888889, 69.6388888888889
), Rain = c(79.2, 79.2, 79.2, 79.2, 79.2, 79.2), Year_Bef = c(2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2004), Year_Bef_Two = c(2004, 2004, 2004, 
2004, 2004, 2004)), .Names = c("Staz", "Year", "Season", "Avg_T", 
"Min_T", "Max_T", "Moisture", "Rain", "Year_Bef", "Year_Bef_Two"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

From what you can see there is a variable named 'Season', defining the season of the data. I would like to split the weather variables ('Avg_T', Min_T', 'Max_T', 'Moisture', 'Rain') for every season, but having them in the same row. So, I would have just one row per study area for every year, containing information about seasonal data.

I tried to do that with the 'cast' and 'dcast' commands in the 'reshape' and 'reshape2' packages but it didn't work.

May somebody help me?

Thanks,

Jacopo

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's say your data lives in `df`. I `rbind` `df` to `df` and change the season in the latter half of `df` to summer so that we have more than 1 season present:

```
df <- rbind(df, df)
df[7:12,]$Season = 'Summer'
```

Then I get rid of the last two columns in `df` (they don't seem to be doing anything):

```
df = df[, -c(9,10)]
```

Now, we're ready to use the `reshape` function:

```
r_df <- reshape(df, timevar = 'Season', idvar = c('Staz', 'Year'), direction = 'wide')
```

I think that should give you what you're looking for.